# Unable to use @EnableJpaRepositories in multi module spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, gradle, module, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to move break up a small java spring boot microservices project into a multi-module Gradle project.

When I have worked on my own projects in the past I have leaned towards having a package for every type of component i.e controller, entity, repository, model, service, configuration, datasource, facade... etc.

Now I have realised 2 things...
1) I would prefer to have a organise my project by domain area NOT component types
2) I should use modules, not packages to organise my project.

Now most things seem to work like this except the fact that because I don't have all my spring repositories in one package, I cannot use @EnableJpaRepositories annotation. I know in a purely package based project I can use it in a package higher in the hierarchy and it would scan all packages below it and pick out any repositories.

I'm not sure how to get around this without having a single package that contains all the repositories.

I almost always organised my projects using only packages so I accept that I may just be misunderstanding the implications of using modules.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The basePackages is an array, not single value, so this should work `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"package.a", "package.b"})`. Or am I misreading what you're asking?

Comment: ok thanks. I think we are on the same page. how will this work across module boundaries? I tried to put a config with this annotation in each package but to no avail. my app starts fine but I can't visit any of my urls as my repositories arent being exported.

Comment: sorry I meant i put the config in each 'module'.

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about Gradle and cannot give any more insight

Comment: ok no problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced with the same issue and I've found the answer here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8134.

You need to add AutoConfigurationPackage annotation. One more thing - I use org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration configuration in spring.factories resource. It give me possiblity to autoload a module if it added just to runtime dependencies.